# moving vertices like sculpting in java

Tags: java, lwjgl

how  to create drag vertices like this application [link](http://abau.org/dilay/)
in the video in this link there is a drag tool i want to duplicate it in java 
what 3d library that i should learn to help to load model and execute that function 
this is the original model before grapping vertices

[image]

this is the model after sculpting
[image]

```
 //just some code so i can submit my question
    System.out.println("Hello world");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: While I appreciate the `just some code so i can submit my question` approach that is not entirely what you are supposed to do. You should provide code that is actually part of your problem. In other words: What have you tried so far, what are your results, where are you stuck? What are the results of your research? We are not going to just hand you a piece of code that does what you want, we are willing to help you get there though when you showed some effort though.

Comment: i am not asking for a  piece of code i am just asking for library that i should study to help me excute the idea as i metioned in the question @Ben